Amitsur's theorem
I have been reading Amitsur's theorem from the book titled 'Central Simple Algebras and Galois Cohomology' by Gille and Szamuely. There in section 5.4, they proved Amitsur's theorem that for a Severi-Brauer variety $X$, kernel of the restriction map $Br(k)\to Br(k(X))$ is precisely generated by the central simple algebra associated to $X$. In the proof i.e. $\textit{Proof of Theorem 5.4.1}$ they said because of theorem $5.2.2$ (which is that if $d$ is the period of $[X]$ then there is an embedding of $X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{N-1}$ such that after base changing to $\bar{k}$ it is isomorphic to the $d$ uple embedding.) Then it is directly written in the book that there is a divisor on $X$ which after base change becomes isomorphic to $d$th power of a hyperplane.
I am unable to figure out the last statement i.e. why such a divisor on $X$ should always exist?
